# non-scamming job-matching sites

Tags: freelance-websites

I am coming from the other side: I am an employer.  I am looking for a site that screens developers for me.  yes, I actually have some jobs.  freelancer.com seems, for the most part, have turned into a scamming site.  what are good recommended sites with filtering of projects and developers?

I can document the problem with freelancer.com .  I recently posted a job description for a wordpress/php development on freelancer.com .  Within a day I had about 50 bids.  Exciting.  Alas, reading the responses made me somewhat suspicious.  For one, I asked everyone who bid to try out an existing website I owned---and I can see how many actually tried it out.

So, I decided to post another job:

```
**Project Description**

most proposals I have received on my real proposal request seems
to have been quasi-automated spam.  so, to check who is just
responding without information, here is another request:

   replicate the entire google infrastructure in wordpress and php.

 should be easy in php and wordpress, right? if you respond to this
 one with a bid, obviously you must be reading my RFPs in great detail.

 Project ID: 8424001
```

To my surprise, I received 80(!) bidders, most claiming to have carefully read my requirements and being confident to satisfy them.  Some added a few pretense questions.  (on my blog, I name the responders, too.)

I feel like a male in the ashley madison data base (see [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/almost-none-of-the-women-in-the-ashley-madison-database-1725558944)).  alas, this still leaves me with a dilemma.  I need a freelance-hiring site that has the quality that stackexchange has!

Comment: Hey there. Welcome to the dark side good sir. A few sites I would recommend (and freelance on) is outsource.com / codersclan.net / stackoverflow careers (I'm sure there are tons of programmers in SO Career looking for contractual projects too) and yes, freelancer.com lol

Comment: Envato too is another one but the rates are a tad bit higher than the others though

Comment: peopleperhour.com has a good online repute too but I have never tried it so I can't say much about it from my own experience.

Comment: @Andrew put that information into an answer, and **explain exactly how it solves the op's problem**

Comment: @CanadianLuke I'm on my phone right now good sir. Will do that as soon as I'm on pc.

Comment: I tried peopleperhour now.  interestingly, the bidders seem less scammy and there are at least some reasonable ones...but they don't curate much, either, and they do have a good number of likely scams, too.

Comment: Try posting your job on Upwork, but not for public. In project settings choose 'Invite Only' and pick good candidates self. If freelancer's job success score less of 85% don't work with him.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about HIRING freelancers, not WORKING as a freelancer.

Comment: I work full time on upwork.com and have 5k+ hours billed on there. It does have a lot of chancers. I find a lot of clients have a budget that is too low ("design me a circuit board for $50!") and give no details ("give me teh c++ codez, plz"). As long as you screen people, have decent specs and have a reasonable budget, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a good experience with the simple development job (for a microsite) that I posted on Upwork.com. I received a reasonable number of bids (20 or so), then communicated with several developers. In some cases, I sensed the responder was unlikely to be the person working on my project, and I avoided those bids. When I found a good match, I requested a Skype chat at the beginning of the job as assurance that the developer was knowledgeable (and human). Overall everything went smoothly. Upwork facilitated good communication between us during the job. 
Best wishes for finding just the right people.